# Animating a font size change in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, animation, fonts

Hey Simple little app for educational purposes, its a simple uitableview and I want users to be able to use a uislider to adjust the font size as needed. The code I have now works to change the font but only when the view is updated, ie when i pull up or down the table view to reveal other cells. I'd like the font change to be reflected immediately as a user moves the uislider if possible, here's the code that I have working half way:

```
  -(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

  static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:   SimpleTableIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:       SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];

   NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
   cell.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
   cell.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[fontSlider value]];

   cell.image = image;
   return cell;


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an IBAction for the fontSlider for the "Value Changed" option as follows:

```
-(IBAction) refreshResize
{
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

That should work. setNeedsDisplay refreshes the screen.

Comment: sounds like it would work i havent touched this project in a while but I do appreciate the response.